# AEM 6.2 AccessDeniedException when loading clientlibs

Tags: aem

After upgrading from AEM 6.1 to 6.2 I started seeing the following exception in the logs when loading a page on the author.

```
ERROR 2017-05-05 12:15:02.329 [172.19.0.1 [1493986502136] GET 
/etc/designs/tello/clientlibs_ps.min.js HTTP/1.1] 
(com.adobe.granite.ui.clientlibs.impl.HtmlLibraryManagerImpl) - Cannot 
load js libraries
javax.jcr.AccessDeniedException: null
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl$1.perform(NodeImpl.java:177)
            at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl$1.perform(NodeImpl.java:168)
            at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.perform(SessionDelegate.java:208)
            at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.ItemImpl.perform(ItemImpl.java:112)
            at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl.getParent(NodeImpl.java:168)
            at com.adobe.granite.ui.clientlibs.impl.HtmlLibraryManagerImpl.loadLibrary(HtmlLibraryManagerImpl.java:1545)
            at com.adobe.granite.ui.clientlibs.impl.HtmlLibraryManagerImpl.loadLibs(HtmlLibraryManagerImpl.java:1475)
            at com.adobe.granite.ui.clientlibs.impl.HtmlLibraryManagerImpl.assertLoaded(HtmlLibraryManagerImpl.java:1336)
            at com.adobe.granite.ui.clientlibs.impl.HtmlLibraryManagerImpl.assertResolved(HtmlLibraryManagerImpl.java:1354)
            at com.adobe.granite.ui.clientlibs.impl.HtmlLibraryManagerImpl.getLibrary(HtmlLibraryManagerImpl.java:982)
            at com.adobe.granite.ui.clientlibs.impl.HtmlLibraryManagerImpl.getLibrary(HtmlLibraryManagerImpl.java:967)
            at com.adobe.granite.ui.clientlibs.impl.HtmlLibraryManagerImpl.getLibrary(HtmlLibraryManagerImpl.java:960)
```

As the exception suggests AEM is having issues loading my clientlibs, but I'm not sure how to fix it and what exactly has changed in AEM 6.2. I haven't seen any documentation that would explain that. It happens when I load any custom page or even when I try to load http://localhost:4502/siteadmin or http://localhost:4502/miscadmin (in both cases the page is blank). Any help would be useful.

Comment: 6.x to 6.2 upgrade can be done in various ways. If you have used in-place upgrade the security ACL definitions would have been upgrade. If you have done a migration from old 6.1 to new 6.2 instance then security won't have been migrated. Which method did you use?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've since realized that our custom modules, when deployed, were overriding the default rep:policy configuration that AEM comes with.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have permissions to those pages . Check the ACL permissions of the logged-in user here ... http://localhost:4502/useradmin .

Check with your admin if you don't have access to above URL .

Comment: Thanks. In the state AEM was in I wasn't even able to see that screen, but I've fixed the issue - please see my comment to the first suggestion above.